# Jade, express, node.js: Cannot GET /index.html showing in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I cant understand why I'm getting this error on my browser when I try to display my `index.jade` file:

> Cannot GET /index.html

My `app.js` file is a follows:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('views', './src/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});


app.get('/books', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Your books are here');
});

app.listen(port, function(Error) {
    console.log('Running server on port ' + port);
});
```

and my file structure is as follows:

```
-> app.js
-> public
-> src
   -> views
      -> index.html
      -> index.jade
```

Any help would be great

Thanks :)